# Passing query string with PrettyFaces

Tags: prettyfaces

I'm working with JSF2 and **PrettyFaces** for creating a 'SEO-friendly URLs'. 
Now I'm facing a problem when I want to pass parameters after the PrettyFaces is creating a new url those parameters will been delete and i want to avoid that.

I will explain it with an example: 
Currently when hitting this url: 
http://www.mysite.com/index.jsf?param1=value1&param2=value2 
After the **PrettyFaces** I'm getting this url: 
http://www.mysite.com/

But I want it to be like that, so when hitting this url:
http://www.mysite.com/index.jsf?param1=value1&param2=value2 
After the **PrettyFaces** i'll get this url: 
http://www.mysite.com/?param1=value1

**Please note**: That I only want to pass specific parameters. from the example above, only `param1` should be passed.

My configuration on the 'pretty-config.xml':

```
<url-mapping>    
    <pattern>/</pattern>    
     <view-id>/jsp/index.jsf</view-id>    
</url-mapping>
```

Comment: Do I understand that you want to remove some parameters from the URL after redirection, but that some should be preserved?

Comment: @Lincoln - Yes, some of the parameters should be passed and some should be preserved. But, if it can't be done, I prefer to pass all the query string.
From
http://www.mysite.com/index.jsf?param1=value1&param2=value2 
to:
http://www.mysite.com/param1=value1&param2=value2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually surprised that the query string is *not* being preserved. I would guess that something is else is going on, other than prettyfaces. What version of PRettyFaces are you using? I'm also guessing that this *is* a problem with PrettyFaces, that this was a bug in the version you're using, but I think that's unlikely.

The *only* thing the `url-mapping` you've pasted should do is perform an internal forward from "/" to "/jsp/index.jsf". It will not do any client redirection from "/index.jsf" to "/"; this is why I think there is something else at play here. (See the code for reference: https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/config-prettyfaces/src/main/java/org/ocpsoft/rewrite/prettyfaces/UrlMappingRuleAdaptor.java#L213)

With regard to stripping out certain query parameters and leaving others, then I highly suggest looking at the Rewrite framework (which is the new core of PrettyFaces), you can use it to build very custom rewriting rules: http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/ and http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the info. I'll update if it's works for me.

Comment: Ok. Let me know how it goes. I'll do my best to make sure we get this working.